# Save Data permanently

Tags: c++

I am working on a project with qt, I need to save data(file path and password) permanently so I can get it or modify it any time even when I exit my application and rerun it.
I thought to solve it with an encrypted xml file but I want to do it without trace.

Comment: What does it have to do with cpu registers?

Comment: You want to *save data* without *leaving a trace*..? I think you need to clarify your requirements.

Comment: @LucTouraille and permanent..

Comment: thank you all for your answers @Dani I thought that may be there is a way to save it in a register some how

Comment: @ Luc Touraille, I want to save data about my encrypted file (path and password) safely that any body can not  broke my encrypted file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either use a file or some other platform specific database mechanism, like Windows' registry. But then it would leave a trace; you can't hope to store something locally and don't leave a trace without rootkiting the operating system (and even that would leave a trace in the hardware, after all, you are writing your data to the drive).

One thing you can hope to do without leaving a trace, is to store the data remotely in some server via the network, since network activity usually is not logged (but can be observed), but I can see 2 problems with this approach:

1) it may be pose some privacy concern to your user (if I were an user of your application, I would not like too see my data sent over the wire to an unknown server);

2) how could you identify the information so that you can retrieve it? You could use some hash with the user name and computer hard drive id and network interfaces MAC adresses, but if some of these change, the data would be lost. You could also generate an unique id for each installation of your application, but it would require you to store that ID locally, and that would be *a trace*.

Local cryptography to prevent reading/tampering with the data is inherently insecure, because you will need to have some repeatable mean to retrieve the key. How would you do it?  If you simply hardcode it in your application, it is easily retrievable by some binary file reader. It can't be on a file named 'key.txt', for obvious reasons. You can compute it at runtime with some complicated algorithm, but you will always need to have it loaded into memory at some point, from where it can be retrieved by someone willingly enough.

Comment: thank you @lvella that was interesting, I am agree with you about the second approach I don't think it fits , I will see what can I do with Windows' registry, thank you one more time.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly not possible to save something on the computer without a trace. Everything is visible to root user.

But if you do not want to let others to change it, you can encrypt it, hide it and set it read-only and root edit permission only. But not to let any one find it is impossible. (are you trying to make a virus?) Even if you put in the BIOS, there is way to find it.

Comment: @oumaya: The goal of most cryptography is to make the viewing of the data very difficult but not impossible.  Remember, the 'heavier' the encryption, the more time will be spent decrypting.

Comment: thank you for your time, my point here to save data about my encrypted file the path and password and I want to hide those informations that any body can not break my encrypted file.